# How word character is interpreted in character class?

Tags: javascript, regex, character-class

`\w` - stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` [**Character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

But i am not able to understand how it is interpreted inside character class.

So when i use

`[\w-~]`

```js
let test = (str) => /^[\w-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

it fails for `T|`

but when i am using

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-~]
```

```js
let test = (str) => /^[A-Za-z0-9_-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

it results in true,

i am not able to understand how these two expressions are different from each other ?

Comment: @Emma it passes as it creates a range in the second expression whereas in first it doesn't, but i am not able to understand why it doesn't create a range in first one

Comment: [Sebastien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572442/3832970) seems complete and correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew reasoning makes sense in his answer, but i am still not getting how engine interpret them as different ? i have searched for this but didn't got any reference or link regarding this

Comment: If you just take it for granted that a regex engine parses the pattern as any other parser char by char, it will be easier for you: when it finds a backslash it remembers it and if the next char is `w`, it knows it is a word class shorthand. If there is a hyphen after it, it is treated as a literal char since the engine knows the previous atom was a shorthand class. With `[A-Za-z0-9_-~]`, the A-Z, a-z and 0-9 are parsed as ranges, the underscore and tilde also are s range jusg because engine reads the pattern char by char. `\w` is not a variable, and is not 'interpolated' in any way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks mate for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the main difference between both your examples is the location of your - character. What's happening here is that in this example:

```
let test = (str) => /^[A-Za-z0-9_-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

It's evaluated as a range, like so:

```
let test = (str) => /^[_-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("|"))
```

will return **true**.

Where in this one:

```
let test = (str) => /^[\w-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

Since **\w** is a set of characters in and of itself, it's evaluating the character **-** by itself.

The position of - and it's surrounding can make a huge difference in how it's interpreted.

You could avoid that situation, altogether, by moving it to the end, like so:

```
let test = (str) => /^[A-Za-z0-9_~-]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

which will return **false**

Comment: Thanks for your time mate, Any document or link to read where it states `Since \w is a set of characters in and of itself, it's evaluating the character - by itself.` ?

Comment: I don't happen to have anything about that, sorry, it's personal experience with regex that made me realize that that's most likely what was happening, a quick test validated it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess **range** is doing everything here, when you use `^[A-Za-z0-9_-~]+$`

`_-~` matches a single character in the range between _ (index 95) and ~ (index 126) (case sensitive) that's why `T|` get matched and returns `true` but when you use `^[\w-~]+$` it is not forming any **range** of characters like `_-~` to match so it fails and returns `false`

See `^[A-Za-z0-9-~]+$` also returns `false` because it doesn't include the `_` character to make the range `_-~` between `_` (index 95) and `~` (index 126)

```js
let test = (str) => /^[A-Za-z0-9-~]+$/.test(str)

console.log(test("T|"))
```

See https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/5 here on the **EXPLANATION** section.

Comment: In your [first link](https://regex101.com/r/vbLN9L/2) you used `^[\w_-~]+$` whereas i am asking for `^[\w-~]+$` this mate

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes because `^[\w-~]+$` is interpreted as `[A-Za-z0-9]` not as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` that's why you've to include the extra `_` after `\w`

Comment: @CodeManiac but I can see on regex101.com they are saying `\w
Matches any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_].`

Comment: @Alwayys Sunny this deosn't seems the case mate [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X20d7J/1/), even if i don't use `_` it will still match `_` so it's not the case that `\w` will be interpreted as `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: @CodeManiac I think you're right I am going slightly wrong direction mate. :(

Comment: @CodeManiac mate have a look on my edited answer. I guess this time I'm right :)

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_]` this is how `\w` is interpreted, so i am not able to understand why it is not creating any range here, this is what my original says